# How to change text on spinner selection

Tags: java, android

I have a couple of textviews with a couple of spinners lined up in a table. There are 4 choices in the spinners, all of them the same, the first choice being '--'. I want the textview next to the spinner to be red when the default option '--' is selected, and white otherwise.

I coded this to handle this but when you select one spinner's different option, all of the textviews change It's behavior is just really strange.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        switch(parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);}else{textView1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
        case R.id.spinner2:
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);}else{textView2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
        case R.id.spinner3:
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){textView3.setTextColor(Color.RED);}else{textView3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten "break" in your case blocks:

```
case R.id.spinner1:
    if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){
        textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        textView1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    break;
```

and so on.

Comment: Crap -_-. thanks, you were the first so you've got the answer. both up voted. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a

```
break;
```

at the end of each of your cases.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        switch(parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);}else{textView1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);}else{textView2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
            break;
       case R.id.spinner3:
            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("--")){textView3.setTextColor(Color.RED);}else{textView3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
            break;

        }
    }
```